# How to choose which nan in column header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to choose the first nan to be named School while the other nan to be named grade.

Original Column Header:

```
Name Address nan Class Subject nan
```

This is the outcome I want:

```
Name Address School Class Subject Grade
```

---

When i tried this code:

```
df = df.rename(columns={np.nan:'School'})
```

This is my result with my code:

```
Name Address School Class Subject School
```

Answer (score 1):

What I will do

```
s=df.columns.to_series()
s[s.isnull()]=['school','grade']
df.columns=s
```

Comment: I like this one because you don't have to know beforehand, or figure out, the non `nan` column names first.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.columns = ["Name", "Address", "School", "Class", "Subject", "Grade"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the columns, and if you come across an `nan`, then replace it with the right one:

```py
cols = []
count = 1
for column in df.columns:
    if column == np.nan:
        if count == 1:
            cols.append('School')
        else if count == 2:
            cols.append('Grade')
        else:
            cols.append(column)
        count+=1
    else:
        cols.append(column)
df.columns = cols
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify nan without a loop?